# MVC5 Movie example from tutorial connection string issue visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

i was trying to Run the exampe that found on the 
`MVC` tutorial , that named "Movie_MVC"
on this Link::::

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

i am running Visual Studio 2013 ,
i created a database  on the  App_Data folder 
by

App_Data(right click )--> add item ---> data--> database --->database.mdf

and when trying to run the example
i found this exception ::

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while getting provider
>   information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework
>   using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for
>   details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

my Connection String is on the `web.config` is ::::

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
    Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;
    Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you have a problem with the Connection String that
you are using 
i advise you to use this Connection String according to your 
information provided above :

SQL Server Express database in an .mdf file in the `App_Data` folder.

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
    AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;
    Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

for more connection Strings you can visit this link :::

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2012/08/14/sql-server-connection-strings-for-asp-net-web-applications.aspx

Comment: be sure to put 
Initial Catalog=database_name;
at the first time

Comment: and put DatabaseFileName.mdf as you named it

Comment: and User Instance=True

Comment: and  Integrated Security=True

Comment: and  MultipleActiveResultSets=True